# Quasiclassical propagator

Tags: superconductivity, greens-functions, propagator, superfluidity

Sometimes they are referred as Keldysh quasiclassical propagator or Eilenberger propagator.  How the quasiclassical propagator is derived? How they are implement with a simple case of a Green's function?
\begin{equation}
G^{K}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(g^K+\vec{g}^K \cdot \vec{\sigma}) & (f^K+\vec{f}^K \cdot \vec{\sigma})i\sigma_y \\
i\sigma_y(\underline{f}^K+\vec{\underline{f}}^K \cdot \vec{\sigma}) & (\underline{g}^K-\sigma_y\vec{\underline{g}}^K \cdot \vec{\sigma}\sigma_y)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

They come from a quasi-classical expansion of the Dyson's equation (in the context of superconductivity, the Dyson's equations for the normal $G$ and anomalous $F$ Green's function are usually called the Gor'kov equations). They originate from

> Larkin, A. I., & Ovchinnikov, Y. N. (1969). Quasiclassical method in the theory of superconductivity. Sov. Phys. JETP, 28, 1200–1205.
>
> Eilenberger, G. (1968). Transformation of Gorkov’s equation for type II superconductors into transport-like equations. [Zeitschrift Für Physik, 214(2), 195–213.](http://doi.org/10.1007/BF01379803)
>
> Usadel, K. D. (1970). Generalized Diffusion Equation for Superconducting Alloys. [Physical Review Letters, 25(8), 507–509.](http://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.25.507)

and they are many reviews of them, including

> Serene, J. ., & Rainer, D. (1983). The quasiclassical approach to superfluid 3He. [Physics Reports, 101(4), 221–311.](http://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(83)90051-0)
>
> Langenberg, D. N., & Larkin, A. I. (1986). Nonequilibrium superconductivity. Amsterdam: North-Holland.
>
> Wilhelm, F. K., Belzig, W., Bruder, C., Schön, G., & Zaikin, A. D. (1999). Quasiclassical Green’s function approach to mesoscopic superconductivity. [Superlattices and Microstructures, 25(5–6), 1251–1288. Mesoscale and Nanoscale Physics; Superconductivity.](http://doi.org/10.1006/spmi.1999.0710)
>
> Kopnin, N. B. (2001). Theory of nonequilibrium superconductivity. Oxford: Oxford University Press.
>
> Gor’kov, L. P. (2008). Theory of superconducting alloys. In K. H. Bennemann & J. B. Ketterson (Eds.), [Superconductivity (in two volumes), vol. 1: Conventional and unconventional superconductors. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer Berlin Heidelberg.](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-73253-2)

and many other.